# C# COM Interop: how to make a method that takes array parameter by value?

Tags: c#, vba, com-interop, pass-by-value, ref

I'm making a C# interface which my VBA code can call. The method takes an array of string as parameter, and it has to be a `ref` type, pass by value (without `ref` in C#) gives me error when calling the function in VBA.

Error when calling the interop method in VBA:

> Compile error:
>   Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic

Comment: what is the signature of the method?

Comment: @kennyzx currently it's `object[,] Foo(ref string[] input)`, but I want `object[,] Foo(string[] input)` which give me error when calling in VBA.

Comment: add the information and the error message to the question?

Comment: Try this
[Passing string array from VB6 to C#.net][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507416/passing-string-array-from-vb6-to-c-net