# C++/CLI com-Interop: Exposing a reference type property to VBA

Tags: c#, vba, c++-cli, com-interop

After long hours of investigation on exposing C# property that accepts a reference type to VBA, I concluded that it was not possible. In brief, a C# property that is of type double[] or even an object cannot be consumed in VBA like this:

```vba
' Compile Error: Function or interface marked as restricted,
' or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic
oComExposedEarlyBinding.ObjectArray = VBArray

' Run-time error 424: Object required
oComExposedEarlyBinding.PlainObject = VBArray
```

Or for more details:
[C# property exposed to VBA (COM) : Run-time error '424': Object required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976506/c-sharp-property-exposed-to-vba-com-run-time-error-424-object-required)

> I would like to know if C++/CLI would support such an option? i.e.
>   Allowing a reference-type property to be exposed to VBA so that a
>   syntax like the above is valid.

N.B. You can achieve this by using late binding, but losing the intellisense is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in C++/CLI because the property in C++/CLI is composed of two functions a get and a set and in C++/CLI you CAN have a reference function (versus a pointer one).

The same property that is exposed in a similar way in C# won't work.

This property is exposed as expected to COM and there will be no issue setting or getting in VBA:

```cpp
private:
    Object ^_myProp;
public:
property Object %MyProp { 
    virtual Object %get() 
    {
        return *_myProp;
    }
    virtual void set(Object %value) 
    {
        _myProp = %value;
    }
};
```