# How to pass parameters from VBA to a DLL file or an API

Tags: c#, vba, excel, api, dll

I'm trying to delegate a huge processing VBA code to an outside application. My outside application can be a DLL file or an API.
To do that I need to pass parameters from VBA to a DLL file Or the API. These parameters can be string, integer or an Array.
 I already found an example on how to pass Integers from VBA to DLL file

this is my C# code that have as an input three integers which will be sent by VBA. In this example I just generate the DLL file and I call it in VBA,  but I need to do the same with arrays.

```
[Guid("A33BF1F2-483F-48F9-8A2D-4DA68C53C13B")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyFunctions
{
    public MyFunctions()
    {

    }

    public double MultiplyNTimes(double number1, double number2, double timesToMultiply)
    {
        double result = number1;
        for (double i = 0; i < timesToMultiply; i++)
        {
            result = result * number2;
        }
        return result;
    } 
}
```

How can I pass arrays from VBA TO DLL file or API ?

Comment: Where is your vba code?

Comment: How do you invoke this code from your VBA?  How do you pass values to it?  What happens when you try passing a more complex type?

Comment: This is what i'm asking @David I need to do the same thing with more complexe variable types like arrays or matrixs and not only integers.

Comment: @QHarr it's all in the response of this question  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074533/canonical-how-to-call-net-methods-from-excel-vba

Comment: [Pass an array from vba to c# using com-interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027758/pass-an-array-from-vba-to-c-sharp-using-com-interop) ?